Fastreport passing date parameter
I need some help with passing a date parameter to Fastreport.
In C# I am passing the date as:
report.SetParameterValue("@StartDate", new DateTime(2024, 1, 8));
report.Prepare();

In my report query
SELECT P.AccountNumber, P.PolicyStartDate
FROM "Policies" P
WHERE P.PolicyStartDate> @StartDate

However I keep getting error

SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.


Do you have data that is not inside this limit?
